# Get List of players in own club

Tags: fifa-17

In Fifa 17 the squad building challenges are introduced - a fun way to put your unwanted players to use.

However the search options are, at best, mediocre, so succeeding in a more difficult challenge (without buying players) is sometimes very difficult and time consuming. Things would be a lot easier if I could query my players with own searches, so for example a bit of pseudo-sql:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM Players 
WHERE isRare = 1 
AND tier = 'silver' 
AND nation = 'DE' 
AND position IN ('CAM', CM')
```

Is there any way to search my club like that? Or is there any easy way to export players which I have in my club to some sort of CSV or something? This would be huge for the squad building challenges.

Answer (score 1):

One of your best options might be to use the [Ultimate Team Web App](https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app) and go to the "My Club", there you can use the search queries to filter down the players you have and it is much quicker than doing this with a controller (if that is indeed what you're using.) If the players you have don't meet the requirements and you need to buy someone, you can either use concept players or you could also then tie it in with the [futhead squad builder web app](http://www.futhead.com/squad-builder/), and this would allow you to see if your team meets the requirements, as well as giving you live updates about average prices.

You can't use the FIFA web app at the same time as being logged into the game, unfortunately, but using these tools is probably the best way to help you accomplish squad building challenges quicker. Also note that the my club sections does appear within the game, and you can also add concept players by using the search options within the squad selection screen.